# Calculation of change money placed into a label

Tags: c#

I have to place multiple ints into a label. Sometimes one, sometimes 2 or more, depending on the calculation.
It's the calculation of changing money and it's the number of the coin values that has to be shown in the label. 
example: 1 x € 1,00 + 2 x € 0,20 + 1 x € 0,05
where 1,2 and 1 are the ints from the calculation of money change. The change money has to be in as few coins as possible. 
Right now I have the code with a while-loop and a `label.content =` ---------- each time but I know that if the second or thirth one is also given it always shows the last result into the label.
How can I fix this in the most simple way?
Thanks in advance!

```
    private void btnBuy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (given < cost)
            lblAction.Content = "Not enough money";
        else
        {
            change = (given - cost);
            lblChange.Content = "Terug: € " + change;
            lblReport.Content = "Take";
            lblAction.Content = "Take your beverage";
            btnTakeBeverage.IsEnabled = true;
        }


        while (change >= 1M)
        {
            oneEuro++;
            change -= 1M;
            if (oneEuro > 0)
               lblCalculatingchange.Content = oneEuro + " x € 1,00";
        }
        while (change >= 0.50M)
        {
            fiftyEurocent++;
            change -= 0.50M;
            if (fiftyEurocent > 0)
                 lblCalculatingchange.Content = fiftyEurocent + " x € 0,50";
        }
        while (change >= 0.20M)
        {
            twentyEurocent++;
            change -= 0.20M;
            if (twentyEurocent > 0)
                 lblCalculatingchange.Content = twentyEurocent + " x € 0,20";
        }
        while (change >= 0.10M)
        {
            tenEurocent++;
            change -= 0.10M;
            if (tenEurocent > 0)
                lblCalculatingchange.Content = tenEurocent + " x € 0,10";
        }
        while (change >= 0.05M)
        {
            fiveEurocent++;
            change -= 0.05M;
            if (fiveEurocent > 0)
                 lblCalculatingchange.Content = fiveEurocent + " x € 0,05";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the previous value of the label every time a new portion is calculated. Proper way would be adding new part to the label's text:

```
lblCalculatingchange.Content += fiftyEurocent + " x € 0,50";
```

Or even better - you can use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
...
text.Append(oneEuro + " x € 1,00");
...
text.Append(fiftyEurocent + " x € 0,50");
...

// all calculations done
lblCalculatingchange.Content = text.ToString();
```

**Update.** Another, suggested in comments - this allows you to add "+" signs as well:

```
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
...
tokens.Add(oneEuro + " x € 1,00");
...
tokens.Add(fiftyEurocent + " x € 0,50");
...

// all calculations done
lblCalculatingchange.Content = string.Join(" + ", tokens);
```

Comment: This won't include the `+` to separate the numbers. I think I'd build a `List<string>` and then `string.Join(" + ", myList)`

Comment: `text.AppendFormat("{0}  x € 1,00",oneEuro);`

Comment: @TimS., thanks, nice idea. OP's code did not work with pluses, that is why I did not covered them either. But your approach is great for it allows to cover them easily. Added it to the post

Comment: THanks a lot. The code works fine!! Is there any way I can exclude the zero Integers from the label.content. Now I have for example 1 x €1.00 + 0 x € 0.50 + 2 x € 0.20

Comment: @user3163154, of course, just insert something like `if (amount != 0) then add it to the label`

Comment: But with this solution I think it isn't possible to use math signs because it's a String. Or is there a way?                 List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
...
tokens.Add(oneEuro + " x € 1,00");
...
tokens.Add(fiftyEurocent + " x € 0,50");
...

// all calculations done
lblCalculatingchange.Content = string.Join(" + ", tokens);

Comment: Absolutely possible. What you need to do is to execute `tokens.Add` part only if the corresponding amount is not 0. With `+` sings everything should be fine, since we are using them as a string literals, not as a operators